# Why would my PHP session variables only work in specific browsers and fail in others?

Tags: php, session, cross-browser, password-protection

So i am trying to set up a basic user login form. I want to compare the inputs to the existing database. Everything works fine in Firefox. All information is passed. But in : Chrome, Safari, IE. Almost anything else i'm trying. None of the Session data passes?

For instance.

This is my existing code. It works perfectly in Firefox

login.php

```
<?php
    require_once('../../config/sessionHandler.php'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaValidate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div  class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="logForm" name="logForm" method="POST" action="ajax.php">
            <div id="userName-group" class="form-group">
                <label for="txtUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserName" name="txtUserName" placeholder="User Name"  maxlength="9">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtPasswordInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="btnLogout" onclick="location.href = 'logout.php';" name="logout" type="button" value="logout" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

I have some basic HTML with 2 inputs. Username and Password
This utilizes 3 files. my ajax.php, sessionHandler.php, and my JavaValidate.js

sessionHandler.php

```
<?php
if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
{
session_start();
}
$userName= $_SESSION['UserName'];
?>
```

JavaValidate.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#logForm').submit(function(event)
        {
            var logData = {
                'userName': $('input[name=txtUserName]').val(),
                'password': $('input[name=txtPassword]').val(),
            }

            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : 'ajax.php', 
                data        : logData, 
                dataType    : 'json', 
                encode      : true
            })

            .done(function(data)
                {
                    if(!data.success)
                    {
                       if (data.errors.userName) 
                            {
                                $('#userName-group').addClass('has-error');
                                $('#userName-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.userName+ '</div>');
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //APPEND SUCCESS
                        $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
                    }
                })
            .fail(function(data)
                {

                });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

require_once('../../config/sessionHandler.php'); 

//VARIABLE DECLARATION
$formdata = array();
$inputString = $_POST['userName'];
$inputPass = $_POST['password'];


    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $inputString;
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $inputPass;
    $_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors['userName'];

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

When i run this in different browsers i get different results? After i submit the form with the following data:

FireFox

```
Input: "Username", "Password1"
$_SESSION['Username'] = Username
$_SESSION['Password'] = Password1
```

Google Chrome

```
Input: "Username", "Password1"
$_SESSION['Username'] = Username
$_SESSION['Password'] = NULL
```

Safari Browser (On my phone)

```
Input: "Username", "Password1"
$_SESSION['Username'] = Username
$_SESSION['Password'] = NULL
```

For some reason this seems to work exactly as expected on FireFox? yet it seems to go wonky in every other browser. I'm not sure if i am just missing something for different browsers reading Session data differently? For some reason my password session is only visible through firefox? I thought i might use session data to keep it somewhat hidden before hasing.

If anyone could help shed some light on this for me it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all for your time!

Comment: You need `session_start()`

Comment: If that is all you got then I don't see a reason for it work in any browser. Session_start is missing in all code snippets

Comment: You're sending JSON data but you read it from `$_POST`…? That shouldn't work at all either.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to store password into session.
A good practice will be to check if Username and Passwords exists in database,
then store (or not) a value that says this user's session is authenticated.

Comment: @Eugene I was trying to check inputs for SQL injection so i passed it to Javascript to check inputs. Then from there i compare next to database. Isn't it risky to interact with SQL without cleaning?

Comment: @Morjee - The best way to prevent SQL-injection is using prepared statements, but since the password isn't stored plaintext in the database, it is never necessary to clean the password-input anyway. Have a look at [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).